# JavaScript RegEx for extracting value from HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, regex, tags

```
<font color="green">+4,13</font>%
```

I know that I shouldn't use regular expressions for that, but that's a single case where my only html is that so...

how can I **get** "4,13" from the string above?

**EDIT**

Context:

I am sorting a table via jQuery TableSorter. A column contains that html-formatted data and I can't change it. The custom parser I'm writing has a format function, which I currently use for managing currency, percentages and so on...

Now, I want to check, with a regex, if the string that comes to me is a string.

```
format: function(s) {
    console.log(s);
    var stripped = s.replace("<font>","")
                     .replace("</font>", "");
    return jQuery.tablesorter.formatFloat(stripped);
}
```

Comment: Please be more clear what you mean by "striping" or to "get" the value?

Comment: +1 for the disclaimer about knowing not to use regex :P

Comment: more context needed.  Where does this string come from?  Is the Javascript running in the browser?  How does it load the string, and what else does it do with the string? etc.

Comment: I updated my answer to meet your update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for your specific example -

```
var tagtext = '<font color="green">+0.00</font>%';
var keepplusorminus = false;
var myregexp = keepplusorminus ? /[-\+,\.0-9]+/ : /[,\.0-9]+/;
var match = myregexp.exec(tagtext);
if (match != null) {
    result = match[0];
} else {
    result = "";
}
alert(result);
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/LHBp7/

Comment: I could have "+4,13" or "0.00" or again "-7,698". How do I have to modify it?

Comment: I've just updated the answer, I've changed the RegEx so it will accept a full stop as well as a comma.

Comment: one last thing, kind man :))) how can I "keep" the plus or minus (optionally set)?

Comment: @Fabio are you aware that this regex `[,\.0-9]+` will also match a string like ,,,,,,,,,,, or ,.123.,,342 ?

Comment: Answer updated again, set the boolean value to "keep" the plus or minus

Comment: ipr101 you made my day! :D stema I know! However, my data is checked and right, there :)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

If you just want to match numbers

```
[+-]?\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ulme)

Matches for an optional + or - then at least one digit, then an optional fraction with a . or a , as fraction delimiter.

/Edit

Try something like this

```
<font color="green">([^<]+)
```

You will then find the value "+4,13" in the capturing group 1.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ulm2)

If you want to exclude the `+` than add it (maybe optional) before the capturing group

```
<font color="green">\+?([^<]+)
```